# Centered drop shadow using css3, possible?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create drop shadow which is centered with border, don't wanted to use image as background but not sure what would be the first approach.

Not requesting to write code, but if anybody give an idea how to achieve this would be really great.

I am attaching a image for reference, if you notice the in the center of the first, there is a small shadow.[image]

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: Yes I am very much aware about it, but my question is different, I am looking for shadow in bottom center only just below the box.

Comment: You can set the horizontal shadow to 0, and edit the vertical to whatever you like. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9mqxdnLv/1/

Comment: @hakJav thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  position: relative;  
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! @LGSon I think it will work. will give a try now.

Comment: That is a very clever way of doing it +1.

Comment: @Pangloss Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

That shadow you referenced is really much more.  If you look at it closely, it is really the calendar page flipped and with a gradient.  There must be lots of hints at how to do that (it is an Apple style) with transforms and overlays.

More simply, hakJav's comment and fiddle is right.  I have modified the jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5r7vqddt/8/

so it is a little prettier.
Ultimately, to get a gradient fade

```
 border-image:   
  linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgb(your container bgColor here)) 20;
```

will be the way to go.  I included one on that same fiddle.  I am sure there are better ways to do that.  Here is a css-tricks link wit some interesting examples:
[css-tricks border gradient examples](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your input, link has lots of good collection to learn.